# MySQL copy row from one table to another with multiple NOT IN criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

We have an old FoxPro DB that still has active data being entered into it.  I am in the process of writing a series of .bat files that will update a MySQL database for our web applications that I'm working on.

Our FoxPro databases were never set up with unique IDs or anything useful like that so I'm having to have the query look at a few different fields.

**Here's my query thus far:**

```
//traininghistory = MySQL DB
//traininghistory_test = FoxPro DB

INSERT INTO traininghistory
      WHERE traininghistory_test.CLASSID NOT IN(SELECT CLASSID FROM traininghistory)
      AND traininghistory_test.EMPID NOT IN(SELECT EMPID FROM traininghistory)
```

**What I'm After is this:**
I need an query that looks at the 600,000+ entries in the FoxPro DB (traininghistory_test in my code) and compares to the 600,000+ entries in the MySQL DB (traininghistory in my code) and only inserts the ones where the columns CLASSID and EMPID are new- that is, they are NOT in the traininghistory table.

Any thoughts on this (or if you know a simpler/more efficient way to execute this query in MySQL) are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a `outer join / null` check:

```
insert into traininghistory
select values
from traininghistory_test tht
    left join traininghistory th on tht.empid = th.empid 
                  and tht.classid = th.classid
where th.empid is null
```

It's also worth noting, your current query may leave out records since it's not comparing `empid` and `classid` in the same records.

Comment: This looks promising.  I'm getting an error: ` #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` even though the table traininghistory and traininghistory_test are duplicates of the each other.

Comment: @DanKaufman -- specify your column list making sure the columns match: `insert into table1 (col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ...`  This will help you identify the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need * columns.  Mostly for the way our stone-age reporting software is set up.  I tried `select * from tht...` but that is what failed.

Comment: @DanKaufman -- `select *` is the same as `select col1, col2, ... colx` for every column.  So for testing, should be easy to validate which column is the problem.  Do you have an `auto increment` column that could be causing the issue?  If so, you shouldn't include that in the `select` list -- so `*` won't work for that.

Comment: No auto increment fields.  There are 50+ columns (all VARCHAR) so I was mostly trying to shorthand it since we need ALL the info moved over.

Comment: When I try with just one column, EMPID (instead of select *), I get the error `Column 'EMPID' in field list is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 1):

One way ist.

CREATE ONE UNIQUE INDEX ON THE COLUMS (CLASSID, EMPID),

THEN

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO traininghistory SELECT * or fieldlist FROM traininghistory_test;
```

Thats all

Comment: This would be great except the CLASSID and EMPID columns do not contain unique values.  For example, every class I've taken with the agency has my number listed in the EMPID column and all 30 people that took course #8945 all have that listed as the CLASSID for one of their entries.  I love the simplicity of your solution, though.  There is another aspect of this DB that I will be able to use this on so, thanks!

Comment: sorry, ia am not sure if i realy understand. are the data in CLASSID+ EMPID together not unique ? if so, you can build a unique index over both fields. like : ALTER TABLE traininghistory ADD UNIQUE KEY `CLASEMP` (`CLASSID `,`EMPID `);

Comment: That is correct.  For example, employee 9999 has some online courses (which don't have CLASSID numbers- they're just blank) so when I try to `ADD UNIQUE KEY...` it dies on those because there are 10 different classes for employee 9999 with the CLASSID equal to nothing.  Unfortunately, the data coming out of our FoxPro DB is not really organized, nor is it formatted in any way that makes sense.